# Scala 3 : Create Expr[ Int => Int ]

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3

I am using Scala3 macros in a project and I am stuck at creating `Expr` (and `ToExpr`) of a function.

I have something like this :

```scala
case class Foo(f : Int => Int)

given ToExpr[Foo] with {
    def apply(foo : Foo) = foo match {
        case Foo(f) => '{Foo(???)} // <-- here
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to have an `Expr[Int => Int]` to replace `???` above.

---

EDIT: here are some failed attempts by @GaelJ

**1) First try**

```scala
def apply(foo : Foo) = foo match {
  case Foo(f) =>
    val ff: Expr[Int => Int] = '{ (x: Int) => f.apply(x) }
    '{Foo($ff)}
}
```

Gives:

```
|        val ff: Expr[Int => Int] = '{ (x: Int) => f.apply(x) }
|                                                  ^
|                             access to value f from wrong staging level:
|                              - the definition is at level 0,
|                              - but the access is at level 1.
```

**2) Second try**

```scala
def apply(foo : Foo) = foo match {
  case Foo(f) =>
    val ff: Expr[Int => Int] = '{ (x: Int) => ($f).apply(x) }
    '{Foo($ff)}
}
```

Gives:

```
|        val ff: Expr[Int => Int] = '{ (x: Int) => ($f).apply(x) }
|                                                    ^
|                                              Found:    (f : Int => Int)
|                                              Required: quoted.Expr[Any]
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: I added some personal attempts to your post in case it gives some ideas to someone else.

Comment: Thanks for these ideas @GaelJ.
I read all the docs i could find,  and the function are always created inside the macro, so maybe it wasn't thought for this usage

Comment: I don't know if it is what you want, but something like this? `case Foo(f) => Expr(Foo(f))`

Comment: @gianlucaaguzzi this create an infinite recursive call as `Expr(Foo(f))` is implicitly `Expr(Foo(f))(ToExpr[Foo])` which call the `apply` method of `ToExpr[Foo]` (again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the `given` "build blocks" to construct new `ToExpr` : [scala3 docs ToExpr](https://dotty.epfl.ch/api/scala/quoted/ToExpr$.html). From what I see it is not possible to construct a `ToExpr` for a function.